# absolute convergence $\Rightarrow$ convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, absolute-convergence

Prove that if a series $\sum U_n$ is absolutely convergent, then the series is convergent.

**Definition**: Given a series $\sum U_n$, $\sum U_n$ is absolutely convergent if $\sum|U_n|$ is convergent.

**Definition**: A sequence $S_n$ is convergent if and only if $S_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

**Definition**: $S_n$ is a Cauchy Sequence if for any positive $\epsilon$, there exist an integer $N$ such that for any $p>N$ and $q>N$, $|S_p-S_q|<\epsilon$.

Attempt:
$∑U_n$ is absolutely convergent => $∑|U_n|$ is convergent => $∑|U_n|$ is a Cauchy sequence,

Take $T_n=\sum U_n$.

For any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that for any $p>N$, $q>N$, $|T_p-T_q|< \varepsilon$, that is to say,  $\left|\sum\limits_{n=p+1}^q |U_n|\right| <\varepsilon$

Since $\left|\sum\limits_{n=p+1}^q U_n\right| \le \left|\sum\limits_{n=p+1}^q |U_n|\right|< \varepsilon$, then take $S_n=\sum\limits_{n=p+1}^q U_n$, we have $S_n$ as a Cauchy sequence. $S_n$ is convergent, the series is convergent

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: The crux in the proof will be to show that if $\Big||S_p|-|S_q|\Big|<\epsilon$, then $|S_p-S_q|<\epsilon'$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?  (oh, and @John: its "what *have* you tried")

Comment: My attempt is edited above... sorry about the format

Comment: Since you have tagged your question ([tag:real-analysis]), I suppose $(U_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers. (The same question would make sense, for example, in linear normed spaces or in Banach spaces.)

Comment: I have tried to edit your post (for better readability). Please check whether I have not (unintentionally) changed somethings you wanted to say. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier solution (valid only for the real case):
$$-|U_n|\le U_n\le|U_n|\implies 0\le U_n+|U_n|\le2|U_n|.$$
By comparison test, $\sum|U_n|$ converges $\implies$ $\sum U_n+|U_n|$ converges. Finally, $\sum U_n = \sum U_n+|U_n| - \sum |U_n|$ is the difference of two convergent series.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer makes sense. But I got a bit lost when the difference of two convergent series came in. What is it for?

Comment: @QiminLiu, the comparison test can't be applied directly to $\sum U_n$.